# c++: MSVC vs. GCC+CLANG: Handling lambdas capturing class member variables, what is the correct approach?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, g++, clang++

Consider the following code segment which looks very innocent:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

struct foo;

std::list<std::weak_ptr<foo>> wptrs;
std::function<void()> global_func;

struct foo {
    int &a;
    foo(int &a) : a{ a } {  }
    ~foo() {
        global_func = [&] {
            wptrs.remove_if([](auto &x) { return x.expired(); });
            std::cout << "a= " << a << std::endl;
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<foo>(a);
    wptrs.emplace_back(ptr);
    ptr = nullptr;  // object is destroyed here
    global_func();
    return 0;
}
```

When I first encountered the problem on MSVC (Visual Studio 2017), I was working on a TCP/IP server, which tries to clean up a list of `weak_ptr`s to connection objects. The connection object schedules a lambda to clear a list of `weak_ptr`s of connections by calling `weak_ptr<T>::expired()`. I was happy before because everything used to work fine when compiled with clang-6.0+ or g++-7+. Then, I had to use MSVC and received a Read Access violation when destruct was called. I was shocked and tried to generate a minimal example exhibiting the same problem. The minimal example is given above.

The minimal example made the error messages clear, and it seemed like MSVC lambda tries to access to `this->__this->a`. This access sequence suggests that MSVC does not capture the address of `a` (or a reference to `a`), but rather it captures the address of `*this` and acquires access to `a` using this object. Since the `*this` object is completely deallocated when weak ref count becomes zero, I have a memory access error.

Obviously, MSVC approach is radically different than the approach of g++ and clang. So, my question is which compiler is right?

P.S. A simple fix for MSVC case:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

struct foo;

std::list<std::weak_ptr<foo>> wptrs;
std::function<void()> global_func;

struct foo {
    int &a;
    foo(int &a) : a{ a } {  }
    ~foo() {
        global_func = [a = &a] {    // capture a ptr instead
            wptrs.remove_if([](auto &x) { return x.expired(); });
            std::cout << "a= " << *a << std::endl;
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<foo>(a);
    wptrs.emplace_back(ptr);
    ptr = nullptr;  // object is destroyed here
    global_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Members of `*this` are *never* captured: they [can’t be explicitly captured](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#4), and using them [implicitly captures `*this`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#7.1) (by reference regardless of the *capture-default*; consider using `[=,this]` for clarity).  So your second example is the only correct way to do it; GCC and Clang may have been optimizing away the use of `foo::a` since references can’t be rebound.